# Standard icon for current position/location

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I am looking for the glossy blue Google Maps icon for the user's current position. I have seen it being used in several places like in the current version of Google+ on Android:
[image: Google+ screenshot]

The icon also appears on the launcher icon of the Google Maps Android application and as an indicator for the user's current location on the map.

[image: Google Maps launcher icon]

Unfortunately, it is not available in the Android SDK resources (although there is "ic_maps_indicator_current_position.png", but that is a different icon) and I could not find it on the web. But I think that this icon is so well-known -- there must a possibility to use it in your own application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

unzip the official GoogleMap.apk and find it in the resource folder.

[image: on][image: off]

Comment: Thanks, is each icon used for a specific state? I.e. Is the glowing icon for an approximate location where the solid one is a specific location?